# PHP Set Time Limit Ignored

Tags: php

I am getting an execution time error in php 5.4.0: **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 20 seconds exceeded in database\db_funcs.php on line 776.

I have set_time_limit(0) at both the top of my php script and in the file db_funcs.php that is giving me the fatal error.  I have checked

```
ini_get("max_execution_time")=300. 
ini_get("safe_mode") = false.  
ini_get("max_input_time") = -1
```

I have other scripts that are able to run longer than 20 seconds, so i'm not sure why this error is occurring.  I am running this locally on my windows 7 computer for a simulation.

Comment: Did you do a recursive find on `set_time_limit` in *all* included code and imported libraries? Something is setting it at 20, otherwise this can't happen.

Comment: Even if it is set to 20, if elsewhere in the code it is set to 0, it should continue to run right?

Comment: Only if run later, and in time.